# Rebar: "Release mynode uses non existing application mynode"

Tags: erlang, rebar

I've been trying to set up a simple Erlang app using Rebar but can't get it to work.  I followed the instructions on http://skeptomai.com/?p=56 to the letter, and when I run `./rebar -v generate`, I get this error:

```
==> Entering directory `/home/adam/erlang-test3/testing-rebar/apps/myapp'
WARN:  'generate' command does not apply to directory /home/adam/erlang-test3/testing-rebar/apps/myapp
==> Leaving directory `/home/adam/erlang-test3/testing-rebar/apps/myapp'
==> Entering directory `/home/adam/erlang-test3/testing-rebar/rel'
==> rel (generate)
{"init terminating in do_boot","Release mynode uses non existing application mynode"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot (Release mynode uses non existing application mynode)
```

I get a similar error when following https://bitbucket.org/basho/rebar/wiki/ReleaseHandling.  When following http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades, I get:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{dummy_proj,start,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}
```

How do I get rebar to work?  My Erlang version is `Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]`

Answer (score 6):

I also started to learn erlang + rebar and I had the same problem some time ago and
I suppose you have problem in your `reltool.config` file

1. Add path to `lib_dirs`. I have `{lib_dirs, ["../../", "../deps/"]}`
2. Add your app to app list. In my case this is - `{app, MY_APP_NAME, [{incl_cond, include}]}`

**Update:**
You have to rename you app. F.e. to erlangtest1.
My working reltool.config

```
{sys, [  
       {lib_dirs, ["../../"]},  
       {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},  
       {app_file, strip},  
       {rel, "exemplar", "1",  
        [  
         kernel,  
         stdlib,  
         sasl,  
     erlangtest1  
        ]},  
       {rel, "start_clean", "",  
        [  
         kernel,  
         stdlib  
        ]},  
       {boot_rel, "exemplar"},  
       {profile, embedded},  
       {incl_cond, exclude},  
       {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs  
       {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",  
                           "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},  
       {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},  
       {app, sasl,   [{incl_cond, include}]},  
       {app, stdlib, [{incl_cond, include}]},  
       {app, kernel, [{incl_cond, include}]},  
       {app, erlangtest1, [{incl_cond, include}]}  
      ]}.  

{target_dir, "exemplar"}.  

{overlay, [  
           {mkdir, "log/sasl"},  
           {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},  
           {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},  
           {copy, "files/exemplar", "bin/exemplar"},  
           {copy, "files/exemplar.cmd", "bin/exemplar.cmd"},  
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},  
           {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript", "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},  
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},  
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}  
          ]}.
```

Comment: I have ".." in lib_dirs, since reltool.config is in $PROJ_ROOT/rel.  My app is in the app list with the incl_cond and include options.

Comment: Try to add "../../" in your lib_dirs.

Comment: Could you share the whole project somewhere?

Comment: Sure, one is adamcrume.com/erlang-test1.tar.gz, and the other is adamcrume.com/erlang-test2.tar.gz.

Comment: I have experimented with the first sample.
At the first you have to rename your app. F.e. to erlangtest1.
I put my working reltool.config in my answer.

Comment: Even after renaming my app and using your reltool.config file, it still doesn't work.  However, in erlangtest2, I found a spot in the reltool.config file where it was using the node name and should have been using the application name.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: looks like the rebar release handling wiki now has the solution.  If you are using erlang R15B01, it suggests to add {lib_dir, ".."} to the {app, examplar...} tuple.  If you don't do this you will get the "Missing Application Directory" error message.