# Can I use an existing OTP application inside another application or module?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I'm building a system that needs to use a previously built OTP application (lets call it X). If I want to build a new OTP application / module, how can I use the application that already exists from a module, for instance?

I assumed I could call `start`, since it follows the `application` behaviour, and so I built a minimalistic application Y that has the following code:

y.erl:

```
-module(y).
-behaviour(application).

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
  io:format("going to call x_app~n"),
  {ok, _} = x_app:start([]),
  io:format("called x_app~n"),
  y:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
  ok = x_app:stop([]),
  ok.
```

Rebar compiles this code successfully and generates no warnings.
`rel/y/bin/y start` outputs nothing at all (I hoped to get the output of at least one `io:format`)
`rel/y/bin/y stop` outputs `Node is not running!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to list application `x` as a dependent application in your [application's `.app` resource file](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#appl_res_file), or since you're using `rebar`, in your `.app.src` file:

```
{application, your_app,
 [{description,"your application"},
  {vsn, "0.1"},
  {modules,[]},
  {registered, []},
  {mod,{your_app,[]}},
  {env, []},
  {applications,[kernel, stdlib, x]}]}.
```

Note in the very last line that `x` is listed as an application dependency. This results in the Erlang application controller ensuring that `x` is started before it starts your application. And if you're starting your application interactively in an Erlang shell via [`application:ensure_all_started/1,2`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#ensure_all_started-1) this declaration will ensure that `x` is started first before your app starts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So that would imply that if I use `application:start(y).` after proper configuration of `x.app.src` I would see the expected results? I should probably drop the `x_app:start([]).` lines?

Comment: Correct, you should not be starting the app from your own code as you've shown. If `y` depends on `x`, list `x` in `y.app.src` as I've shown and the normal Erlang release startup machinery will ensure they're started in the correct order.

Comment: What about stopping the application? Does calling `application:stop(y).` terminate `x` as well?

Comment: Another question - where must `x` reside at the time of running `rebar generate`? I listed `x` as a dependency and thus it is saved to my `deps/` directory, but running `rebar generate` outputs `Release \"y\" uses non existing application x`.

Comment: Running `application:stop(y)` stops only application `y`. But if you're running a release, shutting down the node will stop all apps in reverse of their start order. As for the `rebar generate` error, maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10476790/409228

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to instructions as to how I should setup my `reltool.config` file? The question you linked seems specific and contains a sample `relltool.config` that has many lines I don't understand.

Comment: There's the rebar wiki: https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Release-handling , see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17482732/409228 , and you might also consider switching to [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org) since it handles releases a lot better than `rebar`.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help!